# Hidden printable text

Tags: c, c89

I build a small program that simply copy the text from an `input.txt` file to an `output.txt` file. It works with no apparent problem with the command:

```
./myCopier.txt < rand.txt > randout.txt
```

on a GCC89 compiler, used for didactic purposes.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
        int c;

        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
                putchar(c);

        /*The text in printf() does not appear anywhere*/

        printf("My theories and toughts!\n");
}
```

Later, I add `printf()` in order to print my thoughts about how the program worked. It compiles without errors or warnings even with restrictive parameters (`-Wall`), but this text does not appear in any place. By any place, I mean both `output.txt` and the standard output.

I am thinking that:

1. The command `./myCopier.exe` alone clearly create an endless loop. Without text input there is no `EOL` character, hence the `print()` command is never reached.
2. So, why when the input is provided, the `printf()` command has no apparent effect? I'd expect the text from `printf()`to appear on the standard output, just when the loop closes and `output.txt` is created. Why does it not occur?
3. My theory is that `./myCopier.txt < rand.txt > randout.txt` does not allow it. For some reason, it makes the program only transfer the input to the output, "ignoring" everything does not come from the input. Am I correct? If so, why?

If you are interested in the problem with deeper detail, here is the assembly code:

http://text-share.com/view/79f31f38

Comment: Could you show what assembly is generated by your compiler?

Comment: Also if memory serves me right, the permission to omit an explicit `return` statement in `main()` was introduced in C99, which would mean that by the C89 standard your program invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: I think there's some misunderstanding somewhere, that what you think is happening is not, in fact, happening. The third point would require something to be magic, to do that comparison. Perhaps you added the `printf()`, but failed to re-compile afterwards and continued to run the old binary?

Comment: @unwind I agree. Unfortunately, I checked several times, getting the same result.

Comment: @Siguza do you mean that a return statement cannot be omitted? In my case, it can be omitted in similar cases. Just to be sure, I added it, with no effect.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Worice Can you delete your binary first, to absolutely rule out using an old version of your code? What does happen when you start it without io-redirection in a terminal window and press CTRL+Z (EOF on Windows) or CTRL+D (on unix)? I assumed you use windows because of the .exe-suffix, but it seems you work with linux?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I am using a gcc89 compiler on Lubuntu guest virtual machine.

Comment: I think you are running a old version of the program. You should control twice your PATH, the executable you actually run and its date.

Comment: @Ctx without io-redirection the program works without run-time error. It does not produce any output because. I suppose, the `while` loop cycles endlessy, not allowing the program to execute the `printf` instruction.

Comment: @Worice As I said, you can signal EOF from stdin by pressing CTRL+D on unix or CTRL+Z on windows terminating your loop

Comment: @Ctx it correctly exits the loops and prints the phrase when the program is launched without I/O redicrection.

Comment: @Worice Then for some reason the output buffer isn't flushed... Does an `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf()` make it work with io-redirection?

Comment: @Ctx it worked! I had not idea of such an option, I will have to further investigate about it.

Comment: @Worice It's still strange, the output buffer should be flushed implicitly on exit! How exactly do you compile and link your binary?

Comment: gcc myProgram.c -o myProgram.x -Wall

Comment: What is a "GCC89 compiler"? Use a more recent version!

Comment: Throw out whatever old junk you are compiling with and get a standard compliant version of GCC. You should be able to compile as `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra`. There aren't any reasons to compile your code as GNU C/gnu90 unless you have very special requirements.

Comment: Thank you @Lundin for your suggestion. Unfortunately, for a while I will have to work with the '89 version. I hope i will change soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omitting the return statement in main() causes undefined behavior in C89/C90.

Normally, returning from main() forces the output buffer to be flushed. If you omit the return statement, anything can happen.

- Try to add `return 0` at the end of main() as was required in C90. GCC in c90/gnu90 mode will warn you otherwise: "control reaches end of non-void function".
- Try to add `fflush(stdout);`.

Comment: Sounds good, but [OP claimed in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44947173/hidden-printable-text#comment76869929_44947173) to have added the `return` statement without success. Possible that OP was mistaken, forgot to compile with changes, etc....

Comment: @DavidBowling If there is an explicit return statement, the program is required to flush the buffers and thereby print the text to stdout by then (if not before). If it doesn't, the compiler is non-conforming.

Comment: Agree, and that was my first thought too. Just pointing out OP's comment.

Comment: In the C standard Theory abstracting from the implementation @Lundin is right. But in the real world gcc exit code on W & L flushes the buffers anyway. Bare metal implementations mostly do not (at least those I use). So those theoretical pointless discussions, do not help in the real world at all.

Comment: @PeterJ It is not theory. The C standard says that calling return from main() is the same thing as calling the exit() function. Which in turn says that upon exit() all buffers must be flushed. If there is no return, then you can't expect the buffers to be flushed, simple as that.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. The issue drove me to to fields that still go beyond my present skills. For now :) In any case, now I have a better grasp on several things that were bothering me.